# Function to Send Email Notification to Author and Admin When Video is Uploaded

Tags: php, wordpress, email, video

I've been struggling; can anyone help please?

I need the Wordpress Templatic Video theme to send a copy of the email that is sent to users when they upload a new video, to admin as well.  Then admin will know to login and publish the video.

The theme should do this, but it doesn't.  So, I'm having a go

The theme URL is: http://www.wordpressdirectorytemplates.com/motaz/video

The function that sends an email when users upload a video is:

```
    /* send email of video post & update submit*/
    global $post;
    $post = get_post($last_postid);
    $author = $post->post_author;
    $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );
    $email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author );
    $title = $post->post_title;

    $to[] = sprintf( '%s <%s>', $name, $email );
    $subject = sprintf( 'Video Post: %s', $title );
    $message = '';

$message .= "<p>Dear $name</p>";
if(isset($_REQUEST['pid']) && $_REQUEST['pid']!="")
{
        $message .= '<p class="sucess_msg_prop">'. __('Thank you for submitting your video at our site, your request has been updated successfully.','templatic').'</p>';
}else{
   /* if user set by default status publish than show different message */
        $theme_settings = get_option('video_theme_settings');
        if(isset($theme_settings['video_default_status']) && $theme_settings['video_default_status'] == 'publish'){
            $message .= '<p class="sucess_msg_prop">'.__('The video will goes live on the site.','templatic').'</p>';                
        }else{
            $message .= '<p class="sucess_msg_prop">'.__('The video will require admin approval before it goes live on the site.','templatic').'</p>';
            $message .= '<p class="sucess_msg_prop">'.__('You will get an email confirmation once your video has been published.','templatic').'</p>';
        }
}
    $message .= "<p>You can view your video on the following link</p>"; 
    $message .= '<a href="'.get_permalink($last_postid).'">'.get_permalink($last_postid).'</a>';    
    $message .= "<p>Thank you</p>";

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

    $fromEmail = get_option('admin_email');
    $fromEmailName = stripslashes(get_option('blogname'));

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 

    wp_redirect(site_url().'/?page=success&pid='.$last_postid);
    exit;
}
```

}

I can get the email to go to admin instead of the user by adding:

```
    $multiple_recipients = array(
'info@example.com');
```

And, then putting $multiple_recipients at the start of:

```
    wp_mail($multiple_recipients , $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

But, this is plain wrong.  Admin does get an email, but the user doesn't get theirs.

I also tried adding a function to the child theme functions file using the WP Codex for help; but, this is incorrect too:

```
    function email_friends( $post_ID ) {
    $friends = 'info@example.com';
    wp_mail( $friends, "New Video Uploaded", 'A new video has been uploaded on http://nuntim.com');

    return $post_ID;

    }
    add_action( 'function video_posts_submition_success_msg_fn', 'email_friends' );
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did a wrong `add action` see the wiki [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action),

is the hook `video_posts_submition_success_msg_fn` exist?
if yes, you can add action with something like this

```
function email_friends( $post_ID ) {

    // may you can play with $post_ID here

    $friends = 'info@example.com';
    wp_mail( $friends, "New Video Uploaded", 'A new video has been uploaded on http://nuntim.com');

    // return $post_ID; // add_action doesn't have return
}
add_action( 'video_posts_submition_success_msg_fn', 'email_friends', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look now.

Why don’t the people down voting this post also be constructive and leave reasons why.  The post seems reasonable to me: I spent all day on the problem, I did lots of research and tried lots of different alternatives; I cannot list them all.  But, I was still stuck.  Isn’t that exactly what this forum is for?

Comment: That works!  However, I did not supply the correct function originally.  I removed the '_fn' from the end of 'video_posts_submition_success_msg_fn'.  The correct function actually is 'video_posts_submition_success_msg'.  I don't care if I get down voted for saying, 'thank you'.

Comment: Glad to hear it,, i also dont know why the others did it. May they don't know what your question mean,,